# adding submenu ruins my navigation ,anyone?

Tags: html, css

now I am finally got my navbar centered I have gotten a submenu in my navbar
now  and I am trying to get it to work but all my links are just ruined :-/
so hope someone could explain to me why it doesnt want to work on the way I am doing it?
I want to keep the style of my navbar, and I am currently playing around with the css to get 
my submenu working but it keeps ruining it :-/.
also when adding display:inline; to my .topnav ul it is not centered anymore grr  ,
I have watched a video but even that would not work with my navbar. 
I know I am doing something wrong but what ??
(can be a litle messy just cause i seperated the codes for testing sorry for that!)

```css
                           /*Topnav*/
.topnav { 
    width: 100%; 
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0; 
 border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
 border-top: dotted #66A761;
 position:relative;
}

.topnav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-left: 15px; 
}

.topnav a {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.topnav a:link {
    color :#9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: #66A761;
}

.topnav input {
    float: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}
 
                           /*submenu testing*/


.topnav ul li ul li {
 display: none;
}
.topnav ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
                           <!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a>
    <ul>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">lactosevrij</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">suikervrij</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">glutenvrij</a></li>
          </ul>
  </li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a>
    <ul>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">basis</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">standaard</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">luxe</a></li>
          </ul>
  </li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
        <input type="text" style="right:0" placeholder="Search..">
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear. Can you please specify what things which has been ruined after the submenu addition

Comment: can you show us how you want your menu to be dispayed. if we remove submenu it is being displayed in blocks

Comment: i posted how i want it , the links centered and the searchbar on the right

Answer (score 1):

```css
.topnav li {
  position:relative;
}
.topnav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

If the intention is that these sub menus work as dropdown you might want to set their positioning to **absolute**, but note that you have to make the wrapper element relative or else it might take the viewport as anchor.

Comment: .topnav li ?? and .topnav li ul ?? dont u mean the other way around ? cause the list item is under the unordered list right ??

Comment: @Webdesignerinclass, nope, actually topnav has a list element, and inside of this one there is a new unordered list, so to apply the css only for these submenues that's the correct order, you can try it. Remember that based on this code, .topnav is a div, but it contains the main unordered list

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean but it sounds like you want a horizontal nav with dropdown sub-menu items.

E.G:

```css
/*Topnav*/

.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0;
  border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
  border-top: dotted #66A761;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.topnav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 7px;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav ul li ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
}

.topnav a:link {
  color: #9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #66A761;
}

.topnav input {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}


/*submenu testing*/

.topnav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

.topnav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="aboutblank.html">lactosevrij</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutblank.html">suikervrij</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutblank.html">glutenvrij</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="aboutblank.html">basis</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutblank.html">standaard</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutblank.html">luxe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: that about how i need it to be but u cant go to the links cause it will dissapear after the first link in a browser

Comment: works fine here in the snippet but as soon i open it in my browser it just closes cause of the gap ??

Comment: and its not centered in the middle also to mutch space between the links

Comment: really need it to be as it is in my other snippet only than with the dropdown ,instead of all the space in between and gotta be able to use all links , haha this one really got me stuck

Answer (score 0):

i changed the whole thing again and got it to react only got 2 problems with it

**1** i can only get on the first link in the submenu, as soon as i slide down with my cursor it just closes before i hit my other link/links. (while in the snippet it works)

**2** cant center my links in the middle under my logo on the page as it is , the spaces between it is perfect.

```css
                           /*Topnav*/

.topnav {
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0;
      border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
      border-top: dotted #66A761;
      position: relative;
}

.topnav ul {
      display: inline;
   text-align: left;
}

.topnav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 7px;
      padding: 0;
      text-indent: 0;
      position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
      -o-transition: all 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.2s;
}


.topnav a {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
      color: #FF00E0;
}

.topnav a:link {
      color: #9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
      color: #66A761;
}

.topnav input {
      float: right;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
}


                          /*submenu testing*/


.topnav ul li ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
   padding: 5px 5px;
 
}

.topnav ul li:hover ul li {
      display: block;
}

.topnav ul li ul li {
      display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a>
    <ul>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">lactosevrij</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">suikervrij</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">glutenvrij</a></li>
          </ul>
  </li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a>
    <ul>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">basis</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">standaard</a></li>
             <li><a href="aboutblank.html">luxe</a></li>
          </ul>
  </li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
        <input type="text" style="right:0" placeholder="Search..">
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```